# java.lang.SecurityException: No active admin owned by uid 10047 for policy #4 on wipe data

Tags: java, android, device-admin, device-policy-manager

I wants to wipe data remotely using my app but currently I am trying to do it manually from app. But When I try to use wipe data method, It shows security Exception. I have tried to force lock and it shows positive results but give exception during wipe data. Please help me. Thanks.

This is the stack trace

```
java.lang.SecurityException: No active admin owned by uid 10047 for policy #4
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
    at android.app.admin.IDevicePolicyManager$Stub$Proxy.wipeData(IDevicePolicyManager.java:1553)
    at android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager.wipeData(DevicePolicyManager.java:1082)
    at com.test.WipeActivity$1.run(WipeActivity.java:54)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have setup the correct permission for your `DeviceAdminReceiver` implementation class and it's checked as App Administrator in `Settings`

[image]

```
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <uses-policies>
    <wipe-data />
  </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

For more info follow this guide http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

Comment: I have done this already but of no use. This is my xml file

`code`
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <uses-policies>
    <force-lock />
    <wipe-data />
  </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
`code`

Comment: I have solved the problem myself. I have not mentioned access modifier in the receiver class. I have just write it public and my matter solved.

Comment: Hi Xkoppion., I am also facing same issue "security exception" for disable usb debugging in admin app..But where should i change the access modifier .can you please tell me thank you advance

Comment: @bhargavkumar040 give us entire stack trace to help you.

Comment: Hi bhargavkumar040, you have to change the access modifier in your receiver class that listen your call. Change it to public and it may resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the xml file

```
<device-admin xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-policies>
<force-lock />
<wipe-data />
</uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

Change the access modified to `Public` in your receiver class. Make it sure that your receiver class and method are public. If anybody still face any issue after this then let me know.